# Vim color scheme in bash and byobu

Tags: vim, colors, vi, byobu

I have a problem with the vim color scheme installation. I did the following:

1) a folder was created `~/.vimrc/colors`

2) I put the color definition `monokai_pro.vim` there

3) I edited the file .vimrc to include the following:

```
   colo monokai_pro
   syntax on
```

- When using bash the color syntax is NOT working.
- When using vim in byobu the color syntax is working.

The same occurs when I use `:colo color_scheme` directly in vim. 
In byobu this is working, but not in bash.

Please note, that in bash I can only select colors which are present in 
`/usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/`.

I was copying `monokai_pro.vim` to the above folder but it is not helping.

Can you somebody explain why?

Comment: It could be your terminal type setting.  Please edit your question and add the output of the `echo $TERM` command in a `bash` shell.

Comment: yes, you are right. the difference is int terminal type setting: 

bash -> `$ echo $TERM
xterm`

byobu -> `$ echo $TERM
screen-256color`